# AG Grid SectionList - Like Table

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

Using ag-grid enterprise is there a way to make something similar to what React Native calls a "Section List"? So it would display something like:

| A header | Another header |
| --- | --- |
| A |  |
| Alpha | bet |
| Alpha | bet |
| Alpha | bet |
| B |  |
| Beta | gimmel |
| Beta | gimmel |

The rows with "A" / "B" wouldn't have the middle bar (I cannot figure out how to do a colspan in the Markdown markup!).

Example Image from React Native Docs

[image: 1]

Comment: I mean... Row Grouping? Or Master Detail records?

Comment: It sounds like that except the styling is different; notice that there are no ">" (arrows/carets) and the group label should be a complete column.